# Why are kicks so effective in a lightsaber duel?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

From reviewing various movie clips, I tend to notice a 100% kick attack success rate, but a nearly 0% lightsaber attack success rate. Is there a canon explanation for this, or is it simply theatrics? The kicks seem so much slower! Wouldn't legs just get chopped off extremely frequently?

Comment: Survivor bias. There are no movies made about Jedi who missed their kicks.

Comment: Consider this.  Your opponent is coming at you with a weapon that can effortlessly cut off limbs, and he also has legs.  You're going to want to keep all your attention on the thing that can cut off your limbs, and just hope the kicks don't hurt to much.

Comment: I strongly recommend you see the [_Star Wars: The Old Republic_ cinematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjG61DoDzN8) for some _really_ cool lightsaber action.

Comment: It's impossible to cut off a Jedi's legs. You have to go for the right arm.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Obi-Wan Kenobi proves you are wrong ;)

Comment: @TimSparrow - The right arm was already gone in that instance, so he had to go for the nearly impossible leg chop.

Comment: Technically speaking, Anakin was no longer a Jedi at that point, so he had already forfeited his 3 invincible limbs :P

Comment: [Inverse Law of Utility and Lethality](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InverseLawOfUtilityAndLethality)

Comment: True Story: We have no midchlorians in our legs.

Comment: Kicks don't end fights, light saber slashes do. Having nothing but saber-against-saber combat is how you end up with the Obi-Wan vs Vader duel from A New Hope, where nothing happens until one slices the other and its over. Kicks are exciting but they transition into new sequences rather than ending the entire scene.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### In-Universe some of the kicks are from trained martial artist duelists, Out-of-Universe Inverse Law of Utility and Lethality applies

The kicks you see Darth Maul so graciously use in combat were a carefully developed style, allowing that way for a higher chance of success.

From Wookieepedia:

> Most species were known to engage in this kind of combat, and a number of sentient species and cultures also developed it into different martial arts proper; ***just as the various lightsaber combat forms could be applied unarmed, so too could many of these unarmed combat styles be applied with the lightsaber***.
>
> **Darth Maul** and Anoon Bondara were both ***students of the [Teräs Käsi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ter%C3%A4s_K%C3%A4si) martial art, developed by the Followers of Palawa, who became accomplished lightsaber duelists***.

However it could be anticlimatic if lightsaber duels were finished by a quick effective strike; [some people](https://www.popularmechanics.com/culture/movies/a10128/heres-how-youd-really-fight-with-a-lightsaber-16460786/) speculate that in real life a duel with such a weapon would be indeed very short. It happens in many shows that the deadlier the weapon the less frequently it strikes preventing this, tvtropes name this [Inverse Law of Utility and Lethality](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InverseLawOfUtilityAndLethality) and [Inverse Law of Sharpness and Accuracy](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InverseLawOfSharpnessAndAccuracy).

On the other hand short duels can be indeed awesome and very emotive as demonstrated by [Obi-Wan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=no4SxdIIDBE).

Comment: "Käse" is German for "cheese", so the name of the martial arts category sounds like "Terra cheesy" for me.

Comment: @Fabian "Teräs Käsi" is actually Finnish for "Steel Hand." So it sounds like.... steel hand for me.